# XCode Bridging-Header build failed only when archive but success when installing on real phone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7, ios9.3

I have this situation where I was building an iOS app in Xcode and needed to use SHA256 encryption. I created a bridging header, imported the header I needed in it and set the Bridging Header in the build settings. I was testing it with the emulator on iOS 9.3 and on real iPhones with 9.3 (when connecting it directly and running it with Xcode) and everything was building and running fine.

Now the problem is that when I try to archive it I receive *Use of unresolved identifier* errors. Is there something special I need to do or some settings I'm missing? (See image below)

Thanks

- Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)
- iOS 9.3
- Configuration:[image: Configuration]